# How to fetch value from another row within the same data pipleline?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have data loaded and various transformations on the data complete, the problem is there is a parent/child relationship managed in the data - best explained by an example

each row has (column names are made up)

```
row_key    parent_row_key   row_name    parent_row_name
```

some rows have row_key == parent_row_key (their own parent)
some rows relate to another row
(row 25 is the parent to row 44 for example).

In this case, row 25 is parent to row 44.  I need to put row 25's row_name in row 44's parent_row_name. How do I query the data in the pipeline for the value?

Answer (score 3):

Can you not just split the data using a multicast and then do a merge-join against itself?

Comment: certainly an avenue worth trying - the hardest part of the product is learning how to use it to solve problems.

Comment: Needless to say it'd be easier to get whatever system you're querying to do it for you before you bring it into SSIS, but I guess you wouldn't be asking if that were appropriate in your case...

Comment: correct - I may have to persist the data and then do the analysis via some simple Sql Tasks -> at least till I get the hang of the product more.

Comment: +1 - I do find though that the sorting required for merging can cause serious slowdown in larger datasets (Anything over 100k rows). Sorting at the datasource (IE: Your query has ORDER BY) helps tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your data to a temp table in your database, a raw file destination or recordset destination (depending on the size of your dataset). Then you could run through you data again and query your temp data and find the correct parent.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the way Macola (Exact Software) handles transactions.  In their situation, a transaction is added to a table and it includes the reference to the original transaction in the row - for example, if the original transaction was a purchase in january and there is a payment in febrary, the february payment will include the transaction number from the january payment in a column refering to the parent.  Since there is no foreign key relationship, each initial transaction is given a guid that can move between ledgers across the system.

Answer (score 0):

As you say

> I have data loaded and various transformations on the data complete

can I then assume you already have all the data available in a temporary or staging table ?
If so, simply doing an UPDATE of the field should do the trick I guess  ? Assuming not all info might be available in the staging table, you could do a cascaded search for the value from the staging table first and then from the actual table if nothing was found. Doing this in one update would easily outperform doing it row by row. (especially if you have proper indexes available)

```
UPDATE staging_table
   SET parent_row_name = COALESCE(new.row_name, old.row_name, '#N/A#')
  FROM staging_table upd
  LEFT OUTER JOIN staging_table new
               ON new.row_key = upd.parent_row_key
  LEFT OUTER JOIN destination_table old
               ON old.row_key = upd.parent_row_key
```